# Make html validation part of build cycle

Tags: html, visual-studio, validation, build-process

Currently when I build my site I have to manually open validate it at the 3wbc site (means when opera pops up, press ctr+alt+shft+u) for every page.
Is it possible to automatically validate every page whenever I build my pages?

P.s.: This page doesn't validate ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download and install your own copy of the validator - http://validator.w3.org/source/ - and invoke it locally instead of trekking out to w3.org for each page. Still, this requires piggybacking over a web server through plain HTTP or the API. For a simpler solution you may prefer to download the SP library - http://www.jclark.com/sp/index.htm or http://openjade.sourceforge.net/ - on which the W3 validator is based, then invoke the command 'nsgmls' from the command line.

There are of course also many desktop HTML validators that can process a batch of HTML pages at once, which may not be automated, but would certainly be much easier than manually checking each page. For example http://arealvalidator.com/ (Windows), http://www.webthing.com/software/validator-lite/install.html (Unix).

Comment: Thanks, I will look in your sollutions from bottom to top ;)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be best choice for you but there's an Ant task for this: [XmlValidate](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlvalidate.html).

Comment: Good to know, but how could this help me validate my HTML except for the correct opening and closing of tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the HTML files in source control like SVN or Git, you can use a pre-commit hook script to run client-side validators on them. Or if you're feeling adventurous, you could use that method to ping another script on the server that validates the live pages...